# How would multiple ADC channels be processed?

Tags: adc, processing

Looking at this manual,
http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371235h.pdf

I see the following picture related to a DAQ board's ADC,
[image]

Assuming all 4 ADC channels are used, 
how would multiple ADC channels be processed?
Which of the following be more likely?

1. The ADCs collects samples sequentially, 
   i.e.: ADC 0 collects one sample, then ADC 1, then ADC 2, then ADC 3, then back to ADC 0 again, etc.?
2. ADC 0 to 3 all collect samples simultaneously?

Comment: If it's important to your application, I'd ask NI. If we're just taking guesses, I'd say the ADCs would sample in parallel (option #2), otherwise why have multiple ADCs? A single ADC with a 4-channel mux would be a hundred times less complex.

Comment: While not the case here (therefore not making this a dedicated answer) often one fast ADC is employed, and the channels are simply seperate track-and-holds that can be sent to the ADC with an analog multiplexer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It's all stated in the linked documents inside the specification you listed.

> How would multiple ADC channels be processed?

Many ADC systems however, would not take simultaneous samples. Read the data sheet for the ADC or sub-system you are considering.

Comment: Thanks, I may have also confused separate ADC devices with different ADC channels within a single ADC.

Answer (score 1):

The spec sheet at http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/373770j.pdf says they are simultaneously sampled - which is what you would expect for a board designed for capturing acoustic type signals.